# Virtual basic Full screen resizing

Tags: vb.net, resize, fullscreen

I'm making a full screen application in visual basic and is having some issues with full screen and control resizing.

I've looked around both google, stack overflow and youtube for answers but none seems to be working for me. What I have worked my way to is that i need to use anchor or docking or something like that if I am not all incorrect

Edit:
Picture examples:
[image]
The main window in my editor.

[image]
When the program runs in maximized screen

Resolution of the program is 800x600 as its going to be made for a screen with that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use anchor points. You can anchor a control to any side, all sides, or any combinations of sides in its container (the form, usually). When the form is resized, the control is automatically sized accordingly. You can also use the form's resize event and change the size or location of the controls manually when the form size changes.

Comment: I tried the anchor to all sides of the form but it had no effect on the resizing of the controls. I thought about manually resizing it on form_load but I would like to do it the correct way tho

Comment: Maybe you could post an example of what you're trying to do, and what's happening when you try it.

Comment: Screen shots have been added.